# TYPO3 TCA type "select" performance issue

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-tca

Is there a possibility to use the TCA field type "select" for a table which has thousands of entries?

The selectbox with the entries shouldn't be displayed (else the record loads minutes or you get a memory limit or max execution time error), but something like a search field (like the existing wizard "suggest") or a record browser (like TCA type "group" has).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with TCA type "group" and (very important!) setting foreign_table:

```
'config' => [
    'type' => 'group',
    'internal_type' => 'db',
    'allowed' => 'fe_users',
    'foreign_table' => 'fe_users'
],
```

From offical documentation (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Group.html#foreign-table):

> foreign_table: This property does not really exist for group-type fields. It is needed as a workaround for an Extbase limitation. It is used to resolve dependencies during Extbase persistence. It should hold the same values as property allowed. Notice that only one table name is allowed here in contrast to the property allowed itself.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the `group` with `internal_type` set to `db` as an alternative to the `select` type; which does precisely what you need here. This is the only type of field which allows your specific use case.

Alternatives include using a `input` type for the field and fitting it with wizards, then configure the wizard so it replaces the original field and only the wizard is shown.

Don't forget to check your SQL keys for the table you're listing. If your listing uses an un-indexed column you can decrease the time to an extreme degree by simply adding an SQL index for the column(s) you use.

Comment: I fear it has to be type "select" or "inline", because an Extbase Repository only can handle these types correctly - a query on a "subrecord" only seems possible with these types. Example: $query->equals('mySelectField.uid', 123);

Comment: Sounds like something else, possibly your domain model annotations, are to blame for this. There's no reason why Extbase repositories shouldn't handle a `group` type field just as well as any other (valid TCA) type. Perhaps you are not declaring the `allowed` list of tables?

Comment: See `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Mapper\DataMapFactory::setRelations`. If you read this and called functions' bodies you can tell which TCA parameters get used for either type and what qualifies either type to be recognised as a proper relation.

Comment: If I use type "group", I get this error: #1353170925: The relation information for property "..." of class "..." is missing. There are many other having this problem: https://www.google.de/search?safe=off&q=%22The+relation+information+for+property%22+%22is+missing%22&oq=%22The+relation+information+for+property%22+%22is+missing%22
Many of them say "don't use TCA type group".

Comment: This error indicates the table name of the relation was not configured correctly, so most likely you used an incorrect TCA setting to declare the target table. See https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/0bd1746384980d9f6f7387d8638d280443ee843b/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Persistence/Generic/Storage/Typo3DbQueryParser.php#L944 - that's why I linked to the DataMapFactory because it explains the exact TCA settings that get taken as table name. If you need further help perhaps paste your actual TCA ;) EDIT: looks like you found the answer: foreign_table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the old TCA field type 'group', which solves this behavior also in TYPO3 CMS 8

```
'my_select_field' => [
    'label' => 'My select field',
    'config' => [
        'type' => 'group',
        'internal_type' => 'db',
        'allowed' => 'my_foreign_table_name',
        'size' => 1,
        'minitems' => 0,
        'maxitems' => 1,
        'suggestOptions' => [
            'default' => [
                'pidList' => 0,
                'searchCondition' => 'hidden=0',
                'searchWholePhrase' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I know type "group". But unfortunately this field type is not possible, because group can contain records from more than one table and therefore many Extbase operations are not possible. Extbase doesn't support field type "group" for many things, e.g. database queries in a repository like $query->equals('mySelectField.uid', 123);

Comment: That's an incorrect assertion. The `group` type supports single tables just fine - but you control this with the `allowed` setting, not the `table` one.

Comment: Yes, but queries in an Extbase Repository can't handle relations to other tables with TCA type "group", even if you only name one table in option "allowed".

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set the field to "readonly". Of course then one can't edit this field in TYPO3 BE, but if the data is coming e.g. from an external source, this is a disadvantage I can live with.

```
'config' => [
    'type' => 'select',
    'foreign_table' => 'fe_users',
    'size' => 1,
    'minitems' => 1,
    'maxitems' => 2, // it has to be > 1 because else a selectbox is rendered
    'readOnly' => 1, // readOnly because of performance issues
],
```